# UITableView with UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I use storyboard and Auto Layout. I add UISwitch to my cell with tag 5. When I choose first UISwitch and scroll down I see that other UISwitch is also turned on and if I scroll up my first UISwitch is turned off. How to fix this?

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    UISwitch* switchView = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

       return cell;

}
```

Comment: its because of cell reusablity...you need to store indexpath of on swithces and based on that fill your cell

Answer (score 3):

This is because `UITableView` reuse `UITableViewCell` so one cell can be use more than once in different indexPaths, in this situation its your responsibility to maintain the state of `UITableViewCell` subViews. Better place to do this is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you are returning cell add logic to make show/hide `UISwitch` or to select accurate state i.e. on or off, you can keep that flag in dataSource object and then you can check for that flag to make set right state for `UISwitch`

Answer (score 3):

**Try This:**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellSetting";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.settingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        if ([[self.settingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:ROW_PRIVATE_BROWSING])
        {
            self.privateBrowsingSwitch =[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-65, 10, 30, 30)];
            if (ApplicationDelegate.privateBrowsing)
            {
                [self.privateBrowsingSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
            }
            [self.privateBrowsingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [cell addSubview:self.privateBrowsingSwitch];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called you have to replace the specific data that needs to be displayed for a cell at that position. This includes things like labels, images and your UISwitch.

This occurs because UITableViews use a small number of cells that are reused.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath add something like this:

```
switchView.on = [self isSwitchOnForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

Then write whatever logic is required to determine if the switch should be on or not.